# Sort Cursor by 3 columns

Tags: android, cursor

How can I use a Cursor with `nBD.query` to `ORDER BY column1 ASC, then column2 ASC` and finally by `column3 in order ASC` too.

```
Cursor D = nBD.query(NOMBRE_TB, columnas, null, null, null, null, column1, null);
```

In SQL is:

```
Cursor c = nBD.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + NOMBRE_TB + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN1 + " ASC, " + COLUMN2 + " ASC, " + COLUMN3 + " ASC", null);
```

but I'd like to use the `cursor D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add multiple Order By clause in a single string

```
String order = "column1 ASC, column2 ASC, column3 ASC";
Cursor D = nBD.query(NOMBRE_TB, columnas, null, null, null, null, order, null);
```

replace `column` with real column names. This will make your query to be sorted in way you desire.

Answer (score 2):

```
String orderBy = COLUMN1 + " ASC, " + COLUMN2 + " ASC, " + COLUMN3 + " ASC";
Cursor D = nBD.query(NOMBRE_TB, columnas, null, null, null, null, orderBy, null);
```